# Extract all untranslated keys in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

I have an application that needs to be internationalized. 
Currently almost all strings are assigned to a translation key  using `t('.whatever')`.

I want to ensure that all keys are translated to a certain language before we release them. In the development/test environment I can enable `config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true`.

But some parts like `devise` and some others generated with a gem are not covered in the tests and there is no grantee that really all pages are tested before the release.

I would prefer a solution, that extracts all keys and adds them to the `locales/xxx.yml`, preferable with some logic to sort and add the missing keys.

I had a look at the following gems/projects, that did not meet my requirements:

- [LocaleApp](https://www.localeapp.com/) - messed up my locales totally :(
- [i18n-missing_translations](https://github.com/romanbsd/translate) did not show the missing translation keys of the default language

**Additional Information**

Our keys are English, our default language is `:de` but we need to translate everything to `[:de, :en, :fr, :it]`

Comment: Have you had a look at [I18n-tasks](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks)?  You could use their RSpec test to make sure that all keys are translated into all your languages before releasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd go about it:

First, decide which locale is the reference/complete one, let's say it's `:de`

Then launch a rails console (or create a rake task), and initialize the I18n backend as follows:

`I18n.backend.send(:init_translations)`

`I18n.backend.send(:translations)`

gives you access to all translations for all locales, i.e something like

```
{
  en: {
    hello: 'Hello World'
  },
  de: {
    hello: 'Hallo Welt'
  }
}
```

Now pick your reference locale, i.e `I18n.backend.send(:translations)[:de]` and then iterate through all translation keys in the `:de` hash and check whether they exist in the other locales using `I18n.backend.exists?(locale, translation_key)`

Example:

`I18n.backend.exists?(:en, [:errors, :messages, :improbable_phone])`
`I18n.backend.exists?(:en, 'errors.messages.improbable_phone')`

If the key does not exists, I'd add it to the hash with a stub like "## TRANSLATION MISSING##", and finally write the hash as YAML file to disk.

Comment: FWIW: `send` is no longer nessecary in recent rails versions. You can just call `translations`. As a bonus, if you call transalations with `do_init: true`. There is no need for the extra `init_translations` call.

Answer (score 1):

you can also find the missing keys by using `yaml-compare` (a tool i made).

you can find it at https://github.com/dorianmariefr/yaml-compare

and then use it as:

```
yaml-compare config/locales/de.yml config.locales/en.yml de en
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use gem `i18n-tasks`. https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks

You can list unused translations, remove them or translate them automatically with google translate. This gem even supports normalization and It's possible to select only specific languages, which you want to work with.

I suggest to add `gem 'i18n-tasks'` to :development group.